# Skip a step on a multipage form based on field input

Tags: entities

I'm using field group module to create a multipage content creation node. I have one field that if "checked" should make the next button skip to final page of form.

For example a 3-page form, if on the first page the user checks "no" on a field, they will skip the second page when they click next and go to the third and final page.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try on this module [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields).

> Conditional Fields allows you to manage sets of dependencies between
>   fields. When a field is “dependent”, it will only be available for
>   editing and displayed if the state of the “dependee” field matches the
>   right condition. When editing a node (or any other entity type that
>   supports fields, like users and categories), the dependent fields are
>   dynamically modified with the States API. A simple use case would be
>   defining a custom “Article teaser" field that is shown only if a "Has
>   teaser" checkbox is checked, but much more complex options are
>   available.